# choosing PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql

I want to create an "users" table which include a "email address" and/or "userName" `unique` field, should I also add an "id" `int usigned auto_increment` to be the `primary key` or not?

I'm asking because I've seen some textbook examples using an "id" field in such a table with another `unique` field.

Comment: You dont need to, but i always do.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may have not want a unique constraint on e-mails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's best practice.

1. You will use it as foreign key in other tables.
2. You want the key to remain unique (you might want to change username)
3. You want the key to be indexed, index will be much smaller for numeric type, than for varchar.

Comment: why can't I use "userName" field as a foreign key in other tables?

Comment: @csstd Strings are slower to search and index then integers.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `userId` column since indexing your table using `VARCHAR` column data type would be less performant.

Using `INT` is better for performance. They take up less space, and more importantly they are much quicker to compare.

An `INT`comparison can be executed in one CPU instruction. For `VARCHAR`s or `CHAR`s, each character must be compared in turn. That makes every PK lookup faster. If you have join tables, every join select will be looking up against the PK.